# html elements (JSX code) keeps on moving when my webpage is resized

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm creating the following website using react.js and this is how it looks before it is resized:

[screen_shot_website_before_resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agQPI.jpg)

But when I resize it vertically or diagonally, all of the elements go all over the place in the 'availability search bar' and for the options in the navbar as you can see below:

[screen_shot_website_after_resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zcuq.jpg)

screenshots that I took are from the homepage of my website. The code for the homepage is as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
import background from './images/backgroundOption2.png'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faAngleDown, faCalendar } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'


const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="homepage-picture-container" >
                <img src={background} alt="intro_image" />
            </div>
            <div className="check-availabilty-container">
                <div>
                    <h3>Check Availability</h3>
                </div>
                <div id="availability-search-container">
                    <div id="availability-search-sub-container">
                        <div className="room-and-occupancy">
                            <div className="occupacy-paragraph-container">
                                <p>Occupancy</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="line-icon-container">
                                <div className="line">
                                    <p id="room-number-input">1</p>
                                    <p id="room-paragraph">Room</p>
                                    <p id="adults-number-input">2</p>
                                    <p id="adults-paragraph">Adult</p>
                                    <p id="children-number-input">1</p>
                                    <p id="children-paragraph" >Child</p>
                                </div>
                                <div id="icon-availability-search-occupancy"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDown} /></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="check-in-out-date-container">
                            <div className="check-in-paragraph">
                                <p>Check-in</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="check-out-paragraph">
                                <p>Check-out</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="line-icon-container">
                                <div className="calender-icon-container"> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCalendar} /> </div>
                                <div className="line" id="line-spacing-for-calender-icon"><p id="check-in-date">03/12/2021</p><p id="check-out-date" >03/13/2021</p></div>
                                <div id="icon-availability-search-check-ins-outs" ><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDown} /></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="special-rates-container">
                            <div className="specials-rates-paragraph">
                                <p>Special Rates</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="line-icon-container">
                                <div className="line" id="spacing-for-special-rates"><p id="check-in-date">Lowest Available Rate</p></div>
                                <div id="icon-availability-search-check-ins-outs" ><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDown} /></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="button-search">
                            <p>SEARCH</p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>

    )
}

export default HomePage
```

Here's my css code:

```
:root {
  --navBar-border: whitesmoke solid 2px;
  --navBar-width: 10%;
  --onPage-borders: rgb(221, 216, 216) solid 0.5px;
  --button-color1: rgba(10, 93, 248, 0.864);
  --button-color2: rgb(247, 179, 52);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  /* font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif; */
  font-family: "Shippori Mincho B1", serif;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;

  /* font-size: 15px; */
}

.adjust-elements {
  min-width: 900px;
  min-height: 900px;
}
a {
  color: grey;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 60%;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
  /* border: black solid 5px; */
}

/* navbar */
.navbar {
  border: var(--navBar-border);
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  z-index: 5;
}

.rooms-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 4%;
  float: left;
  top: 0;
}

.room-options {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.room-options-hide {
  display: hide;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.room-options ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
.room-options-hide ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.reservation-and-booking-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 10%;
  height: 20%;
  float: left;
  top: 0;
}

.reservation-and-booking-options {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 300%;
}

.reservation-and-booking-options ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.hide-reservation-and-booking-options ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.hide-reservation-and-booking-options {
  position: relative;
  width: 5%;
  float: left;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.gallery-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 5%;
  float: left;
  top: 0;
}

.gallery-options {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 188%;
}

.gallery-options ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.hide-gallery-options ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.hide-gallery-options {
  position: relative;
  width: 5%;
  float: left;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.link-divs {
  width: 4%;
  float: left;
  top: 0;
}

#drop-down-1 {
  position: relative;
}

#drop-down-rooms {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border: black solid 2px;
}

#drop-down-rooms li {
  list-style: none;
}

a:hover {
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  color: orange;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
}

.link-container {
  justify-content: space-around;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#logo-container {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#logo-container img {
  border: var(--navBar-border);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -30%);
}

/* homepage */
.homepage-picture-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  background: no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 45vh;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.homepage-picture-container img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template: repeat(auto-fit);
}

/* homepage-availabilty search */


.line {
  border: var(--onPage-borders);
  margin-top: 1vh;
  border-top: none;
  margin-top: 3.5vh;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  margin-right: 3vh;
  margin-left: 1vh;
  height: 25px;
}

.line-icon-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1vh;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#line-spacing-for-calender-icon {
  margin-left: 5vh;
}

#icon-availability-search-occupancy {
  transform: translate(-1vh, -2.5vh);
  float: right;
}
#icon-availability-search-check-ins-outs {
  transform: translate(-0.6vh, -2.5vh);
  float: right;
}

.room-and-occupancy {
  border: var(--onPage-borders);
  margin-left: 1.5vh;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.occupacy-paragraph-container {
  float: left;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.room-and-occupancy p {
  margin-top: 0.3vh;
  font-size: 1.8vh;
  margin-left: 1vh;
}

.welcome-container {
  margin-top: 1vh;
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 20%);
}

.homepage-picture-container h2 {
  color: whitesmoke;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.contact-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.about-container {
  /* visibility: hidden; */
}

.check-availabilty-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#availability-search-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -125%);
  /* min-width: 70%; */
  border: var(--onPage-borders);
  /* max-height: 6px; */
  /* min-height: 21%; */
  height: 20%;
  border-radius: 2vh;
  min-width: 1000px;
}

#availability-search-sub-container {
  justify-content: space-around;
  transform: scale(0.98, 0.85);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.check-in-out-date-container {
  float: left;
  border: var(--onPage-borders);
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-left: none;
}

.special-rates-container {
  float: left;
  border: var(--onPage-borders);
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-left: none;
}
.button-search {
  float: left;
  border: var(--onPage-borders);
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 18%;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.1vh;
  position: relative;
  background: var(--button-color2);
  border: var(--button-color2);
  border-radius: 1vh;
}

.button-search p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}

.specials-rates-paragraph {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 2vh;
}

#spacing-for-special-rates {
  margin-left: 2vh;
}

.check-in-paragraph {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 5vh;
}

#check-in-date {
  float: left;
}

#adults-paragraph {
  float: left;
  transform: translateX(5vh);
}

#adults-number-input {
  float: left;
  transform: translateX(5vh);
}

#room-paragraph {
  float: left;
}
#room-number-input {
  float: left;
}

#children-paragraph {
  transform: translateX(-1vh);
  float: right;
}
#children-number-input {
  transform: translateX(-9vh);
  float: right;
}

#check-out-date {
  transform: translateX(-0.5vh);
  float: right;
}

.check-out-paragraph {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 4.1vh;
}

.calender-icon-container {
  transform: translateY(2.8vh);
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2vh;
  margin-top: 0.5vh;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 2.5vh;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 3vh;
}

#blocker {
  border: black solid 2px;
}
```

And here's my code for the navbar:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link} from 'react-router-dom';


const NavBar = () => {
    const [isRoomOptionsOpen, setIsRoomOptionsOpen] = useState(false);
    const [isReservationAndBookingOpen, setIsReservationAndBookingOpen] = useState(false)
    const [isGalleryOpen, setIsGalleryOpen] = useState(false);
    const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0)
    const handleScroll = () => {
        const position = window.pageYOffset;
        setScrollPosition(position);
        console.log(scrollPosition)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, { passive: true })
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
        }
    }, [scrollPosition]);
    return (
        <>
            <div className="adjust-elements">
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <div className="navbar" >
                        <div id="logo-container">
                            <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="" width="120px" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="link-container">
                            <div className="link-divs">
                                <Link to="/">HOME</Link>
                            </div>
                            <div className="link-divs">
                                <Link to="/about">ABOUT</Link>
                            </div>
                            {isRoomOptionsOpen ?
                                <>
                                    <div className="rooms-container" onMouseEnter={() => setIsRoomOptionsOpen(!isRoomOptionsOpen)} onMouseLeave={() => setIsRoomOptionsOpen(!isRoomOptionsOpen)}>
                                        <a onClick={() => setIsRoomOptionsOpen(!isRoomOptionsOpen)}>ROOMS</a>
                                        <div className="room-options">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    <Link to="/about">ALL</Link>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <Link to="/about">PREMIUM</Link>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <Link to="/about">DELUX</Link>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <Link to="/about">COTTAGE</Link>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </>
                                :
                                <div className="rooms-container">
                                    <a onClick={() => setIsRoomOptionsOpen(!isRoomOptionsOpen)}>ROOMS</a>
                                    <div className="room-options-hide">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <Link to="/about">ALL</Link>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <Link to="/about">PREMIUM</Link>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <Link to="/about">DELUX</Link>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <Link to="/about">COTTAGE</Link>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
                            {isReservationAndBookingOpen ?
                                <>
                                    <div className="reservation-and-booking-container" onMouseEnter={() => setIsReservationAndBookingOpen(!isReservationAndBookingOpen)} onMouseLeave={() => { setIsReservationAndBookingOpen(!isReservationAndBookingOpen) }} >
                                        <a onClick={() => setIsReservationAndBookingOpen(!isReservationAndBookingOpen)}>RESERVATION/BOOKING</a>
                                        <div className="reservation-and-booking-options">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    <Link to="/about">MAKE A RESERVATION</Link>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <Link to="/about">MY BOOKING</Link>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </>
                                :
                                <div className="reservation-and-booking-container">
                                    <a onClick={() => setIsReservationAndBookingOpen(!isReservationAndBookingOpen)}>RESERVATION/BOOKING </a>
                                    <div className="hide-reservation-and-booking-options">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <Link to="/about">MAKE A RESERVATION</Link>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <Link to="/about">MY BOOKING</Link>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
                            {isGalleryOpen ?
                                <>
                                    <div className="gallery-container" onMouseEnter={() => setIsGalleryOpen(!isGalleryOpen)} onMouseLeave={() => { setIsGalleryOpen(!isGalleryOpen) }} >
                                        <a onClick={() => setIsGalleryOpen(!isGalleryOpen)}>GALLERY</a>
                                        <div className="gallery-options">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    <Link to="/about">THE PROPERTY</Link>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <Link to="/about">FOOD</Link>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </>
                                :
                                <div className="gallery-container">
                                    <a onClick={() => setIsGalleryOpen(!isGalleryOpen)}>GALLERY</a>
                                    <div className="hide-gallery-options">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <Link to="/about">THE PROPERTY</Link>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <Link to="/about">FOOD</Link>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
                            <div className="link-divs">
                                <Link to="/contact">CONTACT</Link>
                            </div>



                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/* <div id="blocker"></div> */}


                {/* <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="navbar" >
                    <div className="link-container">
                        <Link to="/">HOME</Link>
                        <Link to="/about">ABOUT</Link>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                        <a ClassName="link-style">ROOM <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDown} /> </a>
                        <Link to="/reservation">RESERVATION <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDown} /> </Link>
                        <Link to="/gallery">PHOTO GALLERY <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDown} /> </Link>
                        <Link to="/contact"> CONTACT </Link>
                        <Link to="/policy">POLICY</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> */}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default NavBar
```

What's working is if I set `min-width: 1000px` for the `availability-search-container`  , if I minimize the webpage horizontally, the elements stay in place. What I want is to prevent the disorganization of my webpage (as seen in the second screenshot) when it is minimized vertically, horizontally, and diagonally, and have the elements either stay put or auto-adjust according to the size of the webpage when minimized. How do I do that?
And here's a link to my project on codesandbox, if anyone wants to interact with it: https://codesandbox.io/s/clr-website-xyogn.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the element that is wrong is .check-availabilty-container. If so, then use min-height instead of height.